# Queue и Threading

Tags: python, многопоточность, файлы, очередь

Извиняюсь за скорее всего глупую просьбу, ну не могли бы вы мне ткнуть на мои ошибки. Python изучаю недавно, поэтому немного затрудняюсь пока что с поиском правильных решений.
Имеется вот такой код:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, enumerate
import threading
from tradingview_ta import *
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

txt = open(r"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\python\text.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
tickers = []

def worker():
    count = 1
    for s in txt:
        tickers = s.rstrip()
        data = TA_Handler(symbol=tickers, exchange="ASCENDEX",screener="crypto",\
                          interval="1d")
        interval = data.get_analysis().interval
        ticker = data.get_analysis().symbol
        exhange = data.get_analysis().exchange

        if s:
            count += 1
            qput = q.put(interval)
            q.get(qput)
            worksheet.write(f'A{count}', interval)
            worksheet.write(f'B{count}', ticker)
            worksheet.write(f'C{count}', exchange)
            print(interval)
            q.task_done()


q = Queue()

for i in range(1, 30):
    threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

q.join()
workbook.close()
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы из файла txt брались тикеры, далее подставлялись в tickers:

```
data = TA_Handler(symbol=tickers, exchange="ASCENDEX",screener="crypto",   
 interval="1d")
```

после в очередь даю задания и получаю их.
Далее в xlsx файл записываются значения в A1..... intervals
в B1........ tickers
В С1......exchange

Много статей прочитал уже о многопоточности, видимо на начальных этапах сложно усвоить все.
Подскажите пожалуйста на примере моего кода или вашего, как правильно нужно запускать многопоток, чтобы потоки между собой не перебивались и не хватались за одной и тоже одновременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в том, что именно вы пытаетесь ускорить. Насколько я понимаю, основное, что тут нужно ускорять, это этот кусок, где вызываются методы `TA_Handler`. Чтение из файла и запись не настолько уж тормозят, плюс к тому их довольно сложно нормально превратить в многопоточный вариант. Поэтому лучше всего вам сделать по такой схеме:

- написать функцию, которая получает на вход тикеры и возвращает по ним аналитику
- прочитать файл с тикерами
- вызвать `multiprocessing.Pool`, передав ему на вход вашу функцию и список прочтённых тикеров
- проитерироваться по полученному результату, записав его в выходной файл
- да, и ещё нужно не забыть обернуть основной код в отдельную функцию и сделать специальный `if` с проверкой, иначе будут проблемы с многопроцессностью

Таким образом, чтение файла и запись в эксель останутся однопоточными (какими они и должны быть), а теханализ будет произведён многопроцессно, причём практически без усилий с вашей стороны.

Основной кусок кода для понимания:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

# ... здесь остальные импорты

def worker(tickers):
    tickers = tickers.rstrip()
    data = TA_Handler(symbol=tickers, exchange="ASCENDEX",screener="crypto",     interval="1d")
    interval = data.get_analysis().interval
    ticker = data.get_analysis().symbol
    exhange = data.get_analysis().exchange
    return interval, ticker, exchange

def main():

    # ... здесь открытие файла и экселя

    with Pool() as pool:
       for interval, ticker, exchange in pool.map(worker, txt.readlines())
            worksheet.write(f'A{count}', interval)
            worksheet.write(f'B{count}', ticker)
            worksheet.write(f'C{count}', exchange)

   # ... здесь закрытие экселя

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S. Ну а очередь `queue` вам тут вообще не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш код выполняет именно то, что я и хотел. Просто прочитав много статей и просмотрев много видео , чаще упоминали Queue и Threading , как модули для многопотоковых задач. Вычитал что для потоков нужны Threading и Queue , а для процессов multiprocessor

Comment: @Stock С потоками у питона проблемы из-за `GIL`, поэтому лучше использовать асинхронность либо многопроцессность. Многопоточность зачастую упирается в `GIL` и в результате всё выполняется всё-равно в один поток, а код становится при этом гораздо сложнее.

Comment: а с помощью многопроцессорности и асинхронности как еще можно ускорить работу кода?

Comment: В данном случае вряд ли что-то ещё можно сделать. Для того, чтобы использовать асинхронность, нужно, чтобы библиотека, которую вы вызываете, тоже понимала асинхронность. Хотя, вот если вам не важно, в каком порядке будут получены данные, можно попробовать использовать `pool.imap`, данные возможно будут приходить чуть быстрее, но не в том порядке, в каком их запрашивали. А может разницы и не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Как пишут, не бывает глупых вопросов. Но ваш немного не закончен, так как не понятно, что сейчас на выходе у вашего кода относительно ваших желаний, и в чём проблема. Вот вам два моих учебных кода - добавил в них небольшие комментарии. Один код - на простую запись и передачу информации, другой - на работу через Queue.

И советую писать по PEP-8, включая длины строк и пропуски строк, - смотреть неудобно. Внес правки в ваш код в этом отношении.
Да и минимальные комментарии желательно иметь в коде, а не вне его:-)

```
'''
Проводим запись в файл одним потоком, чтение - другим, с простейшей 
передачей информации в поток списком. 
'''
from threading import Thread

def thread_read (file_name, value_holder):
    print('1')
    with open(file_name, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        value_holder[0] = f.read() 

def thread_write (file_name, data):
    f = open(file_name, 'w')
    f.write(data)
    f.close 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_r="read_thread.txt"
    # Способ передачи результата между потоками - списком
    result_holder = [None]
    file_w="write_thread.txt"
    new_th1=Thread (target=thread_read,args=(file_r,result_holder))
    new_th1.start()
    # Ждем, когда new_th1 закончит выполнение
    # Или можно было import time и time.sleep (0.1), например
    new_th1.join() 
    new_th2=Thread (target=thread_write,args=(file_w,result_holder[0]))
    new_th2.start()
```

Вот другой код:

```
'''
20 случайными значениями заполняем Queve, передаём в 4 запускаемых потока.
После этого делаем вывод информации в консоль о том, в каком потоке
произошло извлечение данных
'''
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import queue
import random

def worker(holder):
    for y in range(5):
        name=current_thread().name
        print (f'Process:{name} Value:{holder.get()}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result_holder = queue.Queue()
    list1=[random.randint(0,100) for i in range (20)]
    print(list1)
    for i in list1:
        result_holder.put(i)
    for z in range(4):
        new_proc1=Thread (target=worker,name=str(z), args=(result_holder,))
        new_proc1.start()
        new_proc1.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, на счет комментариев и PEP 8 я обязательно приму к сведению ) чувствую , что не раз еще придется просить подсказок )

Comment: На всякий случай: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Можно и то, и другое. Количество ответов с плюсами не ограничено, но принять можно только один. Я вижу, что пишите в другом ответе,  что он выполняет, что вы хотели, но ответ не приняли при этом.

Comment: извините , я не так давно на этом сайте, еще не весь функционал его изучил ) а пишу в том ответе , так как решил по порядку разобраться с подсказками. Сперва с теми что выше, далее ваши детально изучу. Пока что пробежался поверхностно только. И вы оба мне помогли и ваши решения у обоих являются полезными и нужными мне. Могу ли оба ваших ответа выбрать как  "принятый" ?

Comment: Можете попробовать принять два ответа, но вряд ли получится. Тогда примите ответ @CrazyElf, так как он прямо решает вашу проблему (+1 тоже можете поставить, если он полезен), а мой является (надеюсь) просто полезным (если так, то это +1). Главное - изучайте и получаете знания и пользу:-). Принятый ответ важен не столько из-за баллов, сколько потому, что при поиске в базе знаний люди сразу знают, на что смотреть в первую очередь.