# фиксированное значение переменной

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы из file брались тикеры, поочередно подставлялись в symbol, собирали информацию и сохраняли все в Excel. При этом, чтобы данные input из exchange и interval для всего цикла оставались неизменными

В моем примере кода, все работает ровно 1 итерацию, после по новой начинает запрашивать ввод данных в exchange и interval

```
data = TA_Handler(symbol='Тут данные из file', exchange='Тут, то что введено в exchange', screener="crypto", interval='тут, то что введено в interval')
```

Пример кода:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tradingview_ta import *
import xlsxwriter


exchange = input('Например вводим "ASCENDEX": ')
print('То что ввели в exchange : {}'.format(exchange))

interval = input('Например вводим "1d":  ')
print('То что ввели в interval : {}'.format(interval))


# .... открываем файл , который имеет директорию с файлом , название которого мы ввели в  multi_mode_choose
file = open(r'C:\Users\Stock\Desktop\python\биржи\1\{}.txt'.format(exchange), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
tickers = []

def test(tickers):
    tickers = tickers.rstrip()
    data = TA_Handler(symbol=tickers, exchange=exchange, screener="crypto", interval=interval)

    summary = data.get_analysis().summary
    symbol = data.symbol
    timeframe = data.interval

    return summary, symbol, timeframe


def main():

    count = 1
    # ... здесь открытие файла и экселя
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Crypto Screener.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # ... задаем ширину колонок
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 15)

    # ... заполняем верхние колонки названиями
    worksheet.write('A1', 'SYMBOL', format)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'INTERVAL', format)
    worksheet.write('D1', 'EXCHANGE', format)

    # .... pool.map
    with Pool() as pool:
       for summary, symbol, timeframe in pool.map(test, file.readlines()):

    count += 1

    worksheet.write(f'A{count}', summary)
    worksheet.write(f'B{count}', symbol)
    worksheet.write(f'C{count}', timeframe)
    
   # ... здесь закрытие экселя
    workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Эээ... вынести ввод x1 и x2 до цикла? Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Извиняюсь.  Изначально не уточнил о том , что х1 и х2 они входят в функцию модуля tradingview_ta, где вместо exchange должно быть x1 , а вместо interval будет x2 и они не должно изменятся на протяжении перебора строк из x3 которые пойдут вместо symbol

         tesla = TA_Handler(
         symbol="TSLA",
         screener="america",
         exchange="NASDAQ",
        interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_DAY


Извиняюсь за плохое оформление ответа . Отвечаю с телефона и не смог понять , как оформить табуляцию для кода .

Comment: Пока не вижу, чтобы это что-то изменило. Получили x1, x2. Открыли файл. Запустили цикл по его строкам.

Comment: В первой функции у меня общая инфа , переменные и прочее . Во второй функции main() я запускаю pool.map и первой функции отправляю в iterable (x3.readlines()) и после уже происходят вычисления и расчёты с файлом из x3 . Из моих прошлых созданных тем , мне показали такой пример с pool.map . Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412843/498621

Comment: Вы откуда pool импортируете?

Comment: Вот так попробуйте `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`

Comment: Вот , все делаю так же как показано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412843/498621.  Только сейчас добавил 2 переменные input , и на основе введённых значений в них , запускается работа .

Comment: Вам MBo задает вопросы, а вы как будто отвечаете на что-то другое. Добавьте код в вопрос, чтоб был виден цикл и строки с x1 = ... и x2 = ...

Comment: Да, но Вы не улавливаете сути происходящего. В Вашем случае каждый запускаемый процесс клонирует окружение, и естественно просит повторить ввод. Используйте потоки.

Comment: Namerek, получается через pool.map нельзя подобное будет провернуть? Именно что инпуты сохранялись

Comment: А чем Вас потоки не устраивают? Вам что вычислительных мощностей не хватает или скорости загрузки? Вангую, что второго

Comment: Вощем думайте. Если хотите какой-то помощи кроме общих советов, выкладывайте код, будем поглядеть.

Comment: @Namerek , не подскажите как мой код можно преобразовать через потоки:? чтобы потоки между собой не перебивались и не хватались за задания одновременно?

Comment: Вы пробовали предложенный мной выше вариант? Заменить `from multiprocessing import Pool` на  `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`

Comment: @Namerek, да попробовал и он работает . Изначально не внимательно обратил внимание на это. Спасибо большое за помощь. Скажите пожалуйста а при таком методе, указывать кол-во потоков можно? пока ищу детальную информацию об этом, ну и решил все равно у вас поинтересоваться

Comment: @Stock, даже больше чем на обычном Pool.

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо вы мне очень помогли как новичку. А не подскажите каким методом можно потоки добавить в ThreadPool или может детально описывающую статью подскажите?

Comment: @Stock, честно говоря, вот так на раз, ничего в голову не приходит. Начните с этого https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/paket-multiprocessing-python/klass-pool-modulja-multiprocessing/

Comment: @Stock, кстати, если можете в английский, то вот Вам очень хорошая статья. https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/ (совет... Не пытайтесь осмыслить всего, что там написано, сейчас. Просто уберите ее в закладки. Однажды Вы про нее обязательно вспомните.)